# UnicodeDecodeError when uploading a photo to Azure using Django

Tags: django, azure, file-upload, encoding

I'm working on a server that requires uploading a photo from the client devices, and storing them in Azure blob storage. Following both the Django, and Azure documentation, I created the following snippet:

```
photo = request.data['file']
blob_block = BlockBlobService(account_name=settings.AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                              account_key=settings.AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY)
blob_block.create_container('events')
blob_block.create_blob_from_bytes('events', e1.eventuuid, photo.read(), content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='image/jpeg'))
```

However when returning the photo from storage, I keep getting:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte, and I can't find any other encoding that works.

What encoding should I be specifying, or what part of my code needs to change?